# Exception not caught by catch

Tags: c#, wpf, wia

I want to use WIA in my app, with the code shown below. However the exception in the shown in the picture is not caught by the catch block.

```
WIA.ICommonDialog wiaCommonDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();

while (hatNochSeiten)
{
    try
    {

        AktiverScanner.Geraet = AktiverScanner.GeraeteInfo.Connect();

        WIA.Item geraetObjekt = null;

        geraetObjekt = AktiverScanner.Geraet.Items[1];
        geraetObjekt.Properties["Bits Per Pixel"].set_Value(1);
        geraetObjekt.Properties["Horizontal Resolution"].set_Value(300);
        geraetObjekt.Properties["Vertical Resolution"].set_Value(300);

        WIA.ImageFile scanDatei = (ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(geraetObjekt, ScannerModel.wiaFormatJPEG, false);

        scanDatei.SaveFile(@"C:\scan_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + "_Seite" + seiten.ToString("000") + ".jpg");

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(scanDatei);

        var status = (int)AktiverScanner.Geraet.Properties["Document Handling Status"].get_Value();
        hatNochSeiten = (status & AktiverScanner.Eigenschaftlesen(3087)) > 0;


        geraetObjekt = null;
        scanDatei = null;
        seiten++;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException comEx)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
```

The Debugger breaks with this error, as the scanner is still busy, but the exception should be caught from the second catch block.

[image]

Comment: The code in your question does not match the code in your screenshot.  Is the exception you are seeing being thrown from a different part of your code other than the one shown above?

Comment: It is the same code, I removed the unnecessary parts, so it can be read more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio displays *"Exception Thrown"* (Ausgelöste Ausnahme) dialog, when:

- Unhandled exception is thrown
- You have enabled *"Break When Thrown"* in *"Exception Settings"* for certain exception types and one of these exception types is thrown

In the latter case, it doesn't prevent the exception to be properly caught by `catch` block. When you continue debugging (usually by pressing `F5` or `F10`), program execution will properly jump to the beginning of appropriate handling `catch` block. If you do not want this dialog to appear again for this exception type, uncheck "Break when this exception type is thrown" (*Bei Auslösen dieses Ausnahmetyps unterbrechen*) option or unchek "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" in *Exception Settings* window (*Menu -> Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings*).

If the exception is still not caught and there is appropriate `catch` block, another reason could be mismatch between executed code and actual source code.